# Virutal Server 2012 R2 on VPN and LAN

Tags: vpn, virtual-machines, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm running a virtual server 2012 R2, the host has only 1 physical NIC.
On the server, I have a VPN app, with a kill-switch option (Kill Internet access if not connected to VPN). 
The Kill Switch works a bit too well, as it also kills the LAN/RDP access. I can still access the server via VMWare Console, but that's not optimal.
What the kill switch essentially does is remove the Gateway from the network config and substitutes it with the one obtained from the VPN program.
The program is called Private Internet Access.

What I'd like to do:
Assign a 2nd virtual NIC to the VM, and get the VPN assigned to 1 NIC, and the other one being a static IP address so I can always remote in via LAN.

Is this feasible without VLAN, or a 2nd physical NIC?

Comment: Nope, you would need a second Nic on the internal vlan.

Comment: Will a 2nd virtual NIC do?
Since I can add those via the VMware console. Or does it have to be a physical one?